# With jQuery, assigning value to Select2 select dropdown is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a checkbox that when checked, assign a value to a drop down select box. Problem is, the select drop down is designed with `Select2` and assigning value to the select is not working.

I have looked for the solution for a while but haven't got a clear solution with explanation. I hope, you may help how I can solve the problem. Thanks in advance for the suggestion.

Here is the working example of how it functions 'without Select2'. [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashonko/rsaa5244/1/).

Here is the snippet and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashonko/rsaa5244/) 'with Select2' version of the 'not working' example:

```js
$(".js-example-basic-single").select2();

$(function() {
   $("#geStd").click(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('id') === "geStd") {
         $("select#appearance").val("green");
      } else {
         $("#geStd").prop('checked', false);
      }
   });
   $("select").change(function() {
      if (this.value !== "green") {
         $("#geStd").prop('checked', false);
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-9">
   <input id="geStd" type="checkbox">
   <label for="geStd">Set to standard</label>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <label for="" class="col-md-4">Appearance</label>
   <div class="col-md-8">
      <select id="appearance" name="" class="form-control js-example-basic-single">
         <option value="">Select one</option>
         <option value="red">Red</option>
         <option value="green">Green</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the `change` event to force the select value refresh:

```
$(".js-example-basic-single").select2();

$(function() {
   $("#geStd").click(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('id') === "geStd") {
         $("#appearance").val("green").trigger('change');
      } else {
         $("#geStd").prop('checked', false);
      }
   });
   $("select").change(function() {
      if (this.value !== "green") {
         $("#geStd").prop('checked', false);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your suggestion. It's really exciting to learn something new everyday. Thanks again for the solution.  :)

Comment: No problem! Always a pleasure to help. :)

Comment: I'm having a little problem with the above code if you don't mind to look at is that when there is more than one select and more than 1 value to be sent to assign, what should be the best approach? As you can see in this example with your suggestion that the values are changing but the checkbox is not showing any check. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashonko/rsaa5244/2/). Any suggestion? @jackowski

Comment: Change to: `.trigger('change.select2')`. This way you are triggering the change event only for the select2 elements.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your effort on this lesion.  :)

Answer (score 1):

For this you must call/refresh, using select2 [`change`](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events) event, just add this to your code when assigning new value:

```
 $("select#appearance").val("green").trigger('change');
```

So will be something like

```js
$(".js-example-basic-single").select2();

$(function() {
   $("#geStd").click(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('id') === "geStd") {
        $("select#appearance").val("green").trigger('change');
      } else {
         $("#geStd").prop('checked', false);
      }
   });
   $("select").change(function() {
      if (this.value !== "green") {
         $("#geStd").prop('checked', false);
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-9">
   <input id="geStd" type="checkbox">
   <label for="geStd">Set to standard</label>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <label for="" class="col-md-4">Appearance</label>
   <div class="col-md-8">
      <select id="appearance" name="" class="form-control js-example-basic-single">
         <option value="">Select one</option>
         <option value="red">Red</option>
         <option value="green">Green</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort on this solution. I really appreciate the help.  :)